# epoll architecture problem with bottle neck issue

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, epoll

```
while(m_severRun){

    printf("ServerManager::eventAcceptLoop, epoll_wait\n");
    int event_cnt = epoll_wait(m_epfd, m_events, EPOLL_SIZE, -1);
    if(event_cnt == -1){
        perror("epoll_wait error \n");
        break;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<event_cnt; i++){

        SocketClient *conn = reinterpret_cast<SocketClient *>(m_events[i].data.ptr);


        if(conn->getFd() == m_serverSocket->getFd()){

            printf("ServerManager::eventAcceptLoop, A Client has been connected \n");

            struct sockaddr_in clnt_adr;
            socklen_t adr_sz = sizeof(clnt_adr);
            int clnt_sock = accept(m_serverSocket->getFd(), (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_adr, &adr_sz);

            SocketClient* client = new SocketClient(clnt_sock);
            if(!addClient(client))
                break;
        }
        else{

            if(m_events[i].events & EPOLLRDHUP){
                printf("ServerManager::eventAcceptLoop, EPOLLRDHUP \n");
                removeClient(conn);
                close(conn->getFd());
                continue;
            }

            if(m_events[i].events & EPOLLIN){

                printf("ServerManager::eventAcceptLoop, EPOLLIN \n");
                int recv = conn->recv();

                if(recv <= 0){
                    removeClient(conn);
                    close(conn->getFd());
                }
                else{
                    printf("ServerManager::eventAcceptLoop, A message has been received \n");
                    vector<char> data = conn->getData();
                    addWork(conn, data);
                }
            }

            if(m_events[i].events & EPOLLERR)
                printf("ServerManager::eventAcceptLoop, EPOLLERR \n");
        }
    }//for loop end
}//while loop end
```

I am working on a network programming(tcp) and I have this code. This is my first time using epoll so I am not sure this design is correct. Also, I am using a thread pool (5 child threads) and whenever I read data from epoll I put that on the queue in the thread pool. The problem is that in the read function I can see the bottle neck problem.

In the read function, it calls ObserveSocket

```
int SocketClient::ObserveSock(int sock, int timeout){

    printf("SocketClient::ObserveSock called\n");

    fd_set reads;
    int fd_max;
    struct timeval _timeout;

    FD_ZERO(&reads);
    FD_SET(sock, &reads);
    fd_max = sock + 1;

    _timeout.tv_sec = timeout;
    _timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    return select(fd_max, &reads, 0, 0, &_timeout);
}
```

It watches the socket and if there is no signal for a certain amount of time then it returns 0 to close the socket. I thought I need this code to detect unexpected user disconnection or data corruption (client sent 100 bytes but server received 90 bytes then the server will wait for the last 10 bytes which won't arrive).

I will be very appreciated if you guys can tell me how I can fix the bottle neck problem and any architecture issues on this.

I will also look for any good tutorial that using epoll and covers exception handling in detail.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Inside of recv() function it just calls read function and before I read I call the ObserveSocket

Comment: "In the read function, it calls ObserveSocket" -- What "read" function?  Do you mean SocketClient::recv()?  You have too many calls here to functions you have neither provided nor described...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It watches the socket and if there is
>   no signal for a certain amount of time
>   then it returns 0 to close the socket.

Why?

> I thought I need this code to detectever
>   unexpected user disconnection or data
>   corruption (client sent 100 bytes but
>   server received 90 bytes then the
>   server will wait for the last 10 bytes
>   which won't arrive).

You don't. You will get another read event where the read will return 0 indicating EOS, or an error event.

If you want to implement an inactivity timeout you have to implement it *in the main select loop*. That is, keep track of the last activity time for each socket, and if it gets too long close the socket or do whatever you have to do. Put this testing at the bottom of the select() loop, before you iterate and call select() again.

At the moment every read event is blocking all other select() events for the timeout duration. So your entire server is blocked.

Comment: So you are saying, if client sent 100 bytes but server somehow received 90 bytes only (data corruption or something) then epoll takes case of this problem by read zero? so I don't have to worry about this issue ? Is this what your saying? Thank in advance...

Comment: @LCYSoft in my long experience of forums let me tell you that whenever somebody asks 'so you are saying ...' the answer is invariably 'no'. As in this case. I didn't say any of that; I didn't imply any of that; I didn't intend any of that. If you are only receiving 90 bytes out of 100 the other ten bytes must still be in transit. The correct solution to that is not to block the world with your own personal select() on this particular socket but to return to the select() loop and let it process *all* incoming events, including the next data on this socket. And adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. What if the client disconnected after sending 90bytes only for some reason?

Comment: Then you will get an OP_READ, on which read() will return zero, meaning end of stream. As it says in my answer.